# What would the answer be using Linear Equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, problem-solving

How many ways to arrange HATE...............................................

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You have that: $$4s + c + 10d = 350 \quad \mbox{and} \quad 3s + c + 7d = 260$$
Use these two equations to find the value of $s + c + d$. Now it's on you.